# Is there a way to animate the edges of an image in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation

We have a few icons in our WPF application. We want to do an animation, pretty much like a small beacon of light going around the edges of the animation, just endlessly going around it, and following the silhouette of the icons. We found a way to do it by manually creating a path around the icons and have the beacon follow that path (which matches the silhouette), but it's too much manual work because we have a lot of different shaped icons. We're wondering if there's a way for WPF to do this automatically, so we just have to program it once, and then using on the rest of the icons.

Any suggestion very welcome.

Thanks.

**Edit**

[Something like this](http://www.screencast.com/users/CarloToribio/folders/Jing/media/f3dba8cf-b928-4242-9bae-cc50d04045ae).

Comment: @Carlo is it really just a border you want to be animating? or are these more complex shapes than an ellipse/rectangle/rectangle with round corners?

Comment: Yes to both. I want just the border, and the shapes are complex, one of them is a video camera cartoon.

Comment: @Carlo, this still isn't entirely clear to me. that link you provided animates just the border which is a rectangle with round corners. I can show you how to do that, no problem there. is that all you want?

Comment: @Markus Hütter: Ah ok, here's another example of what I need, this is a more complex shape. Is it possible to use your method here too? http://www.screencast.com/users/CarloToribio/folders/Jing/media/fd1a551e-3ad7-4ef6-b7cb-915490fa00ed

Comment: @Markus Hütter: Also, we have a few more complex shapes, so we're looking for a way to do it automatically. Don't mind the animation inside, we just want to animate the edges.

Comment: @Carlo k, I see, this definately is a little tougher. One more question: what exactly are these shapes? Are these pure WPF objects like Paths or GeometryDrawings, or are these rasterized pictures (like png)?

Comment: @Markus Hütte: Most of them are PNG, we have some XAML versions, but the client didn't provide us with all of them, but I bet in XAML is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Gee. Isn't that overkill to use wpf animation capabilities for that? Can't you just create a bunch of small animations in Photoshop or using something else and just put them in?

Like animated .GIFs. the only problem would be that: if I'm remembering it right, WPF have problems with animating .GIFs as embedded resources. So you have to load them from the disk. Or you can have them as embedded resources, but you have to extract them temporarily to the disk and then load them into your app's window.

Comment: The Image control doesn't show animated GIF images natively, but there are many ways to make it work... I wrote an attached property to make it easier, you can find it [here](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/wpf-display-an-animated-gif-image/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 3.5 SP1 or greater and you are requiring a code solution instead of the animated GIFs, my suggestion would be a Pixel Shader.  You would need to write your own Pixel Shader that does the following:

1. Detect the edges.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/EdgeDetection.aspx
2. Takes an input parameter that can be animated with a storyboard that indicates the position of the beacon.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WpfParentWindowShader.aspx
3. Highlights the edge that is indicated by the beacon position parameter and returns the original color for all other points in the image.

If you haven't worked with Pixel Shaders I would recommend downloading the Shazzam Tool, http://shazzam-tool.com/.  It includes an interactive development environment to create and test your shader on simple images and also includes a decent number of Pixel Shaders with source code to help you learn about them.